# Object cannot be reosloved to a type

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create an SQLiteOpenHelper object but I can't do it because there is an error.

I have the following class:

```
public class Bdoh extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
String bdcons = "CREATE TABLE lugares (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    nombre TEXT, descripcion TEXT, latitud FLOAT, longitud FLOAT, foto TEXT)";  


public Bdoh(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) 
{
    super(context, "lugares", null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(bdcons);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lugares");


    db.execSQL(bdcons);
}

public void insertar() 
{
    Bdoh usrbd = new usrbd (this, "bdlugares", null, 1);


           SqLiteDatabase db = usrbd.getWritableDatabase();

}

}
```

The error is in the insertar method. There, there are two errors:

Bdoh cannot be resolved to a type
SqliteDatabase cannot be resolved to a type

The second error I think is because SQLiteDatabase is not an type defined. But the problem is that I don't know how to open the database in order to write in it.

How can I fix them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bdoh usrbd = new usrbd (this, "bdlugares", null, 1);
```

1. `new usrbd` ...  really ?
2. `Bdoh` constructor needs a `Context` as first parameter, `this` i.e. `Bdoh` object, is not one.